# Slow Serial Connection between Arduino and Python

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, arduino-uno, baud-rate

I currently have a project where my goal is to graph (in real time) the air flow going through an air flow sensor. The sensor is connected via IIC to an Arduino Uno, which is then collects the data and sends it to my COM3 Serial line with a baudrate of 1,000,000. In python, I read, line by line, the Serial line, and then graph the data. My goal is to graph about 500 data points/second (500hz), but it seems that Python is reading in the data too slowly.

Here is a small 'test' I performed:
I blew on the air flow sensor. From the Serial Monitor on my Arduino program, I immediately see the readings spike. However, from Python's console output (which is just reading the serial line and printing out the contents), the spike from my blowing is significantly delayed. The longer the program runs, the more backed up Python gets with keeping up with the Serial line.

From the Arduino side:

```py
Serial.println((double)average, 4);
 //Serial.print(" , ");
 // Serial.println((double)Flow, 4);



 delay(2);
}
```

And on the Python side:

```py
print("PRESS 's' TO BEGIN RECORDING DATA!")

while not pressedStart:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        print("Timer and Program Started!")
        startTime = hour.time()
        pressedStart = True


while pressedStart: #Program begins reading Serial Line when 's' is pressed. 

    while flowData.inWaiting()==0:
        pass

    dataArray = flowData.readline().split(",")
    currentAverage = float(dataArray[0])

    averageArray.append(currentAverage)
    print(currentAverage) #this line is as far as my question goes. Why does Python print out this number
                          #more slowly than Arduino sends it out????
```

Comment: Usually string operations are computationally expensive. What happens if you just do `print(flowData.readline())`  without all the other lines starting from `dataArray = flowData.readline().split(",")`?

Answer (score 0):

Python is a scripting language. It runs through an interpreter and therefore runs very slowly. Although and Arduino micro-controller is very under-powered, it runs faster than your python because python is that much slower. Unless you are willing to have less frequent data points by increasing the Arduino delay, I don't think this can be solved. Good luck still!